pySpark: using the withColumn gives an unexpected error
I have the following code. At the end I'm trying to add the column from Dataframe df2 back into the Dataframe df, aiming to get a Dataframe with three columns (two from the original Dataframe and one additional column from DataFrame df2). However, this gives the following error:
AnalysisException: [MISSING_ATTRIBUTES.RESOLVED_ATTRIBUTE_MISSING_FROM_INPUT] Resolved attribute(s) "value" missing from "value1", "value2" in operator !Project [value1#2, value2#3, value#22 AS value3#24]. ; !Project [value1#2, value2#3, value#22 AS value3#24]
Not sure what's causing this error. Hope that anyone can help me with this?
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
  
# create sample DataFrame  
data = [(6.0, 5.0), (4.0, 3.0), (2.0, 1.0)]  
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['value1', 'value2'])

# Add an additional row to the dataframe
last_row = df.where(F.col('value1')<df.count())
last_row_value = last_row.collect()[0][0]
last_row = last_row.na.replace(last_row_value, 0, 'value1')
df = df.union(last_row)

# loop through each element in the value column and find the closest value  
list_values = []

for row in df.collect(): 
    value2 = row['value2']  
    df2 = df.filter(df['value1'] <= value2)
    list_values.append(df2.collect()[0][0])

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(list_values, FloatType())

# Add column from Dataframe df2 to DataFrame df
df.withColumn('value3', df2['value'])


Please add expected output, helps in testing

Based on my understanding, here is the modified code, let us know your expected output and if the answer aligns with that.
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType

data = [(6.0, 5.0), (4.0, 3.0), (2.0, 1.0)]  
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['value1', 'value2'])

# Add an additional row to the dataframe (update value1 to 0 for the last row)
last_row = df.where(F.col('value1') < df.count())
last_row_value = last_row.collect()[0][0]
last_row = last_row.na.replace(last_row_value, 0, 'value1')
df = df.union(last_row)

# Loop through each element in the value2 column and find the closest value in value1
list_values = []

for row in df.collect(): 
    value2 = row['value2']  
    df2 = df.filter(df['value1'] <= value2)
    list_values.append(df2.collect()[0][0])

# Create a new DataFrame with the list of values
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(x,) for x in list_values], ['value3'])

# Add row numbers to both DataFrames (df and df2) so we can join on this column
df_with_row_num = df.withColumn("row_num", F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy("value1")))
df2_with_row_num = df2.withColumn("row_num", F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy("value3")))

df_with_value3 = df_with_row_num.join(df2_with_row_num, "row_num").drop("row_num")

df_with_value3.show()

Output
+------+------+------+
|value1|value2|value3|
+------+------+------+
|   0.0|   1.0|   0.0|
|   2.0|   1.0|   0.0|
|   4.0|   3.0|   2.0|
|   6.0|   5.0|   4.0|
+------+------+------+


This is exactly what I was looking for. It works. Thanks so much for helping me out.

Glad to know it worked for you :) If you found the answer helpful you can upvote and accept the answer :)
